# SQL - Count number or orders based on DateDiff

Tags: sql

I have a problem.

On my table there are 4 fields: DateOpened, DateApproved, DateAssigned, DateClosed

I need to count all orders closed between a date range.

This is so far what I got:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM Table1
WHERE State = 'Closed'
AND DateClosed BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-10'
```

The parameter I'm missing is getting only the orders that have a datediff >=1. Example: if the the DateOpened = 2015-01-02 and DateAssigned = 2015-01-02, I count this order.

To calculate this I do the following: 
DateDiff from DateOpened vs DateAssigned. If DateAssigned is equals to Null, compare DateOpened vs DateApproved.

If the total days are >=1, I will count these work order.

Comment: Please date your question with the database you are using.  And, if your table has four fields, where is `State` coming from?

Comment: I didn't put the state, because the orders have a lot of fields